# Razorpay not returning payment_id,order_id etc. upon successfull payment

Tags: node.js, razorpay

I have one function that is responsible of creating order using razorpay and verify that order .

The code for that function is : -

```
const paymentMethod = async ()=>{
        
      if(!isAuthenticated())
      {
           toast.error('Please signin to continue');
           history.push('/signin')
            // return <Redirect to='/signin' />

            return;
      }
      
      try{
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(total));
        
        const obj = {
          amount:total
        }

        let data = await fetch('http://localhost:3100/api/checkout',{
          method:'POST',
         headers:{
           "content-type":"application/json",
           Accept:"application/json"
        },
          body: JSON.stringify(obj)
        })
         
        let {order} = await data.json()
        
        console.log(order)
        console.log(order.amount)

        const options = {
          key: "rzp_test_cXj3ybg8fawS9Y", 
          amount: order.amount, 
          currency: "INR",
          name: "YO! Merchandise",
          description: "Pay Please",
          image:yo,
          order_id: order.id,
          callback_url: "http://localhost:3100/api/paymentverification",
          prefill: {
              name: "Aakash Tiwari",
              email: "tiwaryaakash00@gmail.com",
              contact: "8750043604"
          },
          notes: {
              address: "Razorpay Corporate Office"
          },
          theme: {
              color: "#13C962"
          }
      };

        let rzp1 = await new window.Razorpay(options);
        rzp1.open();
      }

      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
   }
```

But this function when call callback_url upon successfull payment it is not passing the payment_id,order_id etc. other neccessary details.
when i try to console.log there the req.body is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

hey i just think you are doing the desruturing of your order wrong. i faced the same issue what you have mentioned but at last i found that i just had done the destructuring wrong.

I guess it's realted with your order_id : order.id <- on this line.

Answer (score 0):

#add this line in app.js in server ========#

```
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```